# Closed form volumes for intersecting modified cylinders

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions, convex-geometry, integral-geometry

This question is somewhat related to the question [Intersecting cylinders](https://mathoverflow.net/q/430504/411249), but where the cylinders are now modified to orbifolds in the hypercube with singularities occurring at the vertices of the hypercube. These orbifolds alone have a volume expressible in terms of the determinant of a matrix. When they intersect transversely what is the volume expressible as? A determinant again?

Let $ \mathcal L^n_+$ be the set of all $n$-dimensional nonnegative random vectors $\mathbf X = (X_1, X_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,X_n)^⊤$ with finite and positive marginal expectations, and let $\mathbf Ψ^{(n)}$ be the class of all measurable functions from $\Bbb R^n_+$ to $[0, 1].$ Then $\zeta(\mathbf X)$ of the random vector $\mathbf X$ with joint CDF $F$ is:

$$\zeta(\mathbf X)=\bigg\{\bigg(\int \psi(\mathbf x)dF(\mathbf x), \int \frac{x_1\psi(\mathbf x)}{E(X_1)}dF(\mathbf x),\cdot\cdot\cdot,\int \frac{x_n\psi(\mathbf x)}{E(X_n)}dF(\mathbf x):\psi \in \mathbf Ψ^{(n)}\bigg)\bigg\}, $$

$$ =\bigg\{\bigg(E\psi(\mathbf X), \frac{E(X_1\psi(\mathbf X))}{E(X_1)},\cdot\cdot\cdot,\frac{E(X_n\psi(\mathbf X))}{E(X_n)}:\psi \in \mathbf Ψ^{(n)}\bigg)\bigg\}. $$

Where:

$$\mathrm{Vol}(\zeta(\mathbf{X}))=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\mathrm{E}\big(|\mathrm{det}~ Q|\big). $$

$Q$ is an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix whose $i$th row is $(1,\hat{\mathbf{X}}^{(i)}), i=1,2,...,n+1.$ Here $\hat{\mathbf{X}}\in \mathcal L^n_+$ is a normalized version of $\mathbf{X}$ in which $\hat{X_i}=\frac{X_i}{\mathrm{E}(X_i)}, i=1,2,...,n.$ And where we have $n+1$ $\mathrm{iid}$ $n$-dimensional random vectors $\hat{\mathbf X}^{(1)},...,\hat{\mathbf X}^{(n+1)}$ each with the same distribution as $\hat{\mathbf X}.$

We know the volume of $\zeta$ in any dimension. I'm interested in the volume of copies of $\zeta$ intersecting.

Take all permutations of $\zeta$ on the vertices of the corresponding $(n+1)$ cube. This means we'll have $2^{n}$ transversally intersecting orbifolds as suborbifolds of the $(n+1)$-cube.

> What are the closed form volumes of these transversely intersecting orbifolds for low dimensions, say $n=1,2,3,4?$